# oracle query to compare all the rows having same id in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Need an sql query which results  those records whose status is complete for a same id. For example, `mytable` is the table name which has various records. We need to find all those ids whose status is complete for that same id

```
id status
12 complete
12  required
12  active
13  complete
13  complete
14  complete
14  required
```

So, query should display
13 complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find the `id`s where all its rows have a `status` of `complete`:

```
SELECT id
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT( CASE status WHEN 'complete' THEN 1 END )
```

Comment: Just a question, I wanted to know how this [ HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT( CASE status WHEN 'complete' THEN 1 END ) ] subquery works. Can you please explain.

Comment: `HAVING`clause has similar effect as the `WHERE` clause, i.e. filtring rows. The difference is in `HAVING` you can reference the aggregated functions sunch as `COUNT` and `SUM` - which is in `WHERE` not possible.